# How to compile pjsip for iphone 3.0

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, compilation, voip

I have been trying to compile pjsip for iphone 3.0 but I have been unable to do so. I have tried following the guides on siphon and voiphone (open souce iphone projects that use pjsip). And apparently I am not the only one that is unable to compile pjsip for iphone 3.0 has anyone been able to do so succesfuly?. How can it be done?. Any help will be greatly apreciated.

Thank you

-Oscar

Comment: There is also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848333/just-info-how-to-build-and-compile-pjsip-for-xcode-using-sample-code-ipjsua-t