# How do you compile the pjsip library for the iPhone SDK version 3.0?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have been trying, without success, to compile the pjsip library for the iPhone SDK version 3.0.  Can anyone point me to a guide on how to do this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347696/how-to-compile-pjsip-for-iphone-3-0

Answer (score 0):

http://www.piemontewireless.net/Pagina_principale