# Implementing VOIP in iphone

Tags: iphone, voip

I am new to iphone development. I want to develop an VOIP application. Anybody give me some ideas to start.I have tried "siphon" and "telephone" open source projects but they did not run.
Thanx for any suggestion.

Comment: You say you're new to iPhone development. Does that mean you're new to software development as a whole? Implementing a VoIP application isn't at all limited to being an iPhone development question. If you're not new to development in general, then I suggest you make your question more specific and ask for help on something particular that isn't working in your VoIP implementation. Else, I think you'd better start with something a little smaller. Trying to go from beginning iPhone Development to developing a VoIP application is too big a step.

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: No i m not new to s/w devlopment.I have devloped s/w in java,but to iphone i am only 3-4 months old. I have problem in compiling pjsip.

Comment: > Check this link 


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493050/ios-open-source-voip-sip-objective-c-code?lq=1][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493050/ios-open-source-voip-sip-objective-c-code?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

For developing iPhone VOIP applications, you will probably want to read the answers to the question "[Open Source VoIP/SIP Objective-C Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493050/open-source-voip-sip-objective-c-code)".

As you seem to have already tried siphon, but were unable to get it to compile, you might be interested in the answers to the question "[How to compile pjsip for iphone 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347696/how-to-compile-pjsip-for-iphone-3-0)" (pjsip is what is used for siphon).

Comment: yeah i have problem in compiling pjsip. will u help me regarding this?

Comment: @medma Read the answer on the question I linked to.  One of the links there has step-by-step instructions for compiling pjsip.

Comment: but it gives error in the last step i.e. "make". The error is : "ld: framework not found CoreServices collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make[2]: *** [../bin/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin9] Error 1 make[1]: *** [pjlib-test] Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 1"

Comment: Did you got any solution for compiling the siphon